# SSD on older laptop configurations as MSI x340

Tags: hard-drive, ssd

I have a MSI x340 laptop which is about two years old. I want to make it faster by replacing the old hard disk with SSD, but I dont know if it is worth it.

The guys from the computer shop told me that there is no way to find what the speed will be, beside testing. Is that true and if it is, has anyone tested this model, or a similar one with SSD?

Comment: It really depends on what your doing... I can test all day with how I use my laptop and it might be entirely irrelevant for you...

Answer (score 0):

What are you doing with the laptop ?, if it is something that requires a lot of disk access it should speed it up quite a bit, boot times with ssd's compared to hard drives with platters are usually much improved.

Comment: I am worried that my hdd interface is slow - serial ATA-150.

Comment: mostly browsing. I also run OpenOffice and Adobe software.

Answer (score 0):

I have laptop like yours and have replaced hdd with intel sdd. yes, it works better. Not so much as desktop, but it's visible.